# C# Randomly distributing strings without repetiotion

Tags: c#, .net, random, shuffle

Hi guys i need some help here i want to distribute 6 strings randomly in 6 buttons as text without any repetition. That is i Want to do some kind of shuffling and distribute it but there will no duplicates each button will hold a unique string. If anyone could post the code it would be great :) Thank you

```
class Card_Deck
{
    public Random r;
    public string ReceiveCards()
    {
        List<string> cards = new List<string>();
        cards.Add("♣ King");
        cards.Add("♦ King");
        cards.Add("♥ King");
        cards.Add("♠ King");
        cards.Add("♣ Jack");
        cards.Add("♦ Jack");

        int index = r.Next(cards.Count);
        var card = cards[index];
        cards.RemoveAt(index);
        return card;

    }
}
```

}

This is in the main form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Card_Deck cd = new Card_Deck() { r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond) };

        button1.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
        button2.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
        button3.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
        button4.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
        button5.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
        button6.Text = cd.ReceiveCards();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We are not a code factory? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? We cannot help those who won't help themselves.

Comment: Sorry i could not save my code that time but now i have so now can you please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }
>
> ```
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label1.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label2.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>
>     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label3.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>     private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label4.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>     private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label5.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>     private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label6.Text = Card_Deck.ReceiveCards();
>     }
>     class Card_Deck
>     {
>         public static Random r = new Random();
>         private static List<string> cards = new List<string>() { "♣ King 1",
>             "♦ King 2", 
>             "♥ King 3",
>             "♠ King 4", 
>             "♣ Jack 5", 
>             "♦ Jack 6" };
>
>         public static string ReceiveCards()
>         {
>             if (cards.Count > 0)
>             {
>                 int index = r.Next(cards.Count);
>                 var card = cards[index];
>                 cards.RemoveAt(index);
>                 return card;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 return "";
>             }
>
>         }
>     } 
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method for doing this would be to implement a shuffle algorithm inside of the  `CardDeck` class. Something like Fisher-Yates.

The problem that you have is that you are re-making the array each time and then grabbing a radom element. This will cause duplication. You choices are to either return an entire shuffled array ( the better one imo ), or to make the deck of cards stateful with a private variable.

```
public class CardDeck {

    private List<String> cards;

    public CardDeck () { 
        cards = { "♣ King", "♦ King", "♥ King",
                  "♠ King", "♣ Jack", "♦ Jack" }.toList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> Shuffle () {
        // shuffle cards here

        var rand = new System.Random();
        return cards.OrderBy( x => rand.Next() ).toList<String>();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var deck = new CardDeck();
        var shuffledDeck = deck.Shuffle();

        buttom1.Text = shuffledDeck.pop();
        buttom2.Text = shuffledDeck.pop();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I am trying to make a card game so i needed it. The game i will make will be a 4 player online game so can you refer any book for networking in C# ?